# How to insert the current date to database then retrieve it?

Tags: php, mysql, database, time, timestamp

```
$query = mysql_query ('insert into pm timestamp values("'.strtotime("now").'")')
echo "<td>".date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $date3)."</td>
```

timestamp in database is `INT(11)`

I am able to get today date but I can't get the current time.

please help thank you !

Comment: Why don't you use the appropriate data type: timestamp. Yes, that's not an UNIX timestamp.

Comment: Do you mean that you store timestamp and only want the date?

Comment: iatboy , yup i want to store the timestamp of the current date and time. and after that i want to echo out the current date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time();
```

Gives you current date and time in unix format - timestamp

```
$query = mysql_query ('insert into pm timestamp values("'.time().'")')
```

and after that when you retreive field value to var $date3 just echo it like you did

```
echo "<td>".date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $date3)."</td>";
```

Comment: time() is to put at the $query or ?

Comment: when i echo , it gives 01-Aug-2014 10:11:04 but the actual date and time should be 01-Aug-2014 04:12 because my time is 4.13pm

Comment: that's beacuse time of your server and your time is not same, different timezone I beleive, use $date3 -21600 to remove 6 hours from your time

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the timestamp directly in your database with MySql and not with PHP. Change the type of your "timestamp" to timestamp and use the appropriate function "NOW()"

Your request would be like that : `INSERT INTO table (timestamp) VALUES 'NOW()'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want timestamp, use time()

```
php > echo time();
1406880195
```